# ASP VB NET List(of T) find method failing in a for each loop

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, list, for-loop, find

Good morning stackers!

I'm designing a massive update page.  Here are the general steps:

1. I have a class called item which has two properties: Equipment number and new due date.
2. I have a textbox where i paste values from Excel, the values consist of two columns divided by a vbtab character: the columns are an equipment number and a new due date
3. A button is clicked and the values from textbox are parsed into a list(of item) and the equipment master builds a string for an SQL criteria for a commandtext.
4. The command fills a dataset from a database which gets equipment number and current due date.
5. I add manually a column to the dataset (new due date)
6. I iterate over the rows of the dataset, and i use the list(of item) find method matching equipment from the list and from the database to get a new due date from the textbox parsed values.
7. Everything is going well, except that when using the find method for more than 1 row in the dataset, the method fails:

Here is the code from point 5 and 6:

```
da.Fill(ds, "Equipments")
dt = ds.Tables(0)
ds.Tables(0).Columns.Add("column_1", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
Dim rw As DataRow
For Each rw In ds.Tables(0).Rows
  Dim strsearch As String = rw(0).ToString
  Dim fequnumb As item = myItemList.Find(Function(p) p.EquipNumber = strsearch)
  rw(2) = fequnumb.DueDate <- Error occurs here
Next
```

Again, if instead of `ftechid.DueDate` I put a static value like `Today()`the code runs fine for the loop and fills correctly the gridview, but if i leave the `ftechid.DueDate` then an error is thrown after the first row:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any help is very much appreciated as to how to use the find method inside a `for..each` loop

Comment: What do you think will happen if the Find cannot match your strsearch variable?

Comment: @Steve That means that the Excel list from the user is outdated and the equipment no longer exists in the database.  This is an error-proof built in the code.  I would not put that value in the gridview from where I'll have another button to update the values after user review.

Comment: I suggest you to use the debugger. Put a breakpoint on the Find line and then check the values of the variable strsearch and the return value in fequnumb. Something is not what you expect to be

Comment: @Steve thanks I'll do that.  I'm doing tests with two equipments, weird thing is that both values do exist in the database so it must be something in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Find function cannot match the string requested it returns Nothing and then you cannot set the due date from a variable that is Nothing. If this is a condition expected from the input then you need to protect the assignment to the new column with something like this.

```
For Each rw In ds.Tables(0).Rows
  Dim strsearch As String = rw(0).ToString
  Dim fequnumb As item = myItemList.FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.EquipNumber = strsearch)
  if fequnumb IsNot Nothing Then
     rw(2) = fequnumb.DueDate <- Error occurs here
  End if
Next
```

If this is not supposed to happen then you need to check your inputs

Comment: You're right, I'm finding that when i Build my list it's saving the same value 6 times. I'll post the updated code when I manage to get it corrected.

Comment: The problem was in step 3. I was building the `list(of item)` in a `for..loop` but forgot to put `item1 = new item` inside the loop in order to reset the values in each pass.
Thanks a bunch for your help